como puedo resolver el orden de ejecucion, armado de bot whatsapp
buen dia. estoy modificando un bot para WhatsApp y tengo un problema con la función gotoFlow. En todos mis mensajes, hay varias opciones, pero siempre hay una opción llamada volver que debería llevar al usuario de vuelta al flujo principal.
El problema es que la función para manejar la opción volver se está definiendo al inicio del código, antes de que el flujo principal esté completamente definido. Como resultado, cuando intento usar gotoFlow para regresar al flujo principal, me da un error porque el flujo principal aún no se ha creado.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema para asegurarme de que la opción volver funcione correctamente y lleve al usuario al flujo principal sin causar errores?


const { createBot, createProvider, createFlow, addKeyword } = require('@bot-whatsapp/bot');
const QRPortalWeb = require('@bot-whatsapp/portal');
const BaileysProvider = require('@bot-whatsapp/provider/baileys');
const MockAdapter = require('@bot-whatsapp/database/mock');
const { EVENTS } = require('@bot-whatsapp/bot');

// Bloque "volver"
const flowVolver = addKeyword(['volver', '0', 'Volver']).addAnswer(
    async (ctx, { state, gotoFlow }) => {
        return gotoFlow(getFlowPrincipal());
    }
)
// Bloque "gracias"
const flowGracias = addKeyword(['gracias', '9']).addAnswer(
    [' Gracias, por su consulta, pero..... paga tus impuesto basura'],
    null,
    null,
)

// Bloques "terciarios"
const flowTerciarioA_1 = addKeyword(['1']).addAnswer(
    [
        'Ingrese al siguiente link:',
        'https://appsvr.mardelplata.gob.ar/Consultas/ConsuCta/Index.asp',
        '*0* - Volver',
        '*9* - Finalizar',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['9', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowVolver, flowGracias]
)

const flowTerciarioA_2 = addKeyword(['2']).addAnswer(
    [
        'Ingrese al siguiente link:',
        'https://appsb.mardelplata.gob.ar/Consultas/ReliquidaCtaCtePasarelas/Index.asp',
        '*0* - Volver',
        '*9* - Finalizar',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['9', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowVolver, flowGracias]
)

const flowTerciarioB_1 = addKeyword(['1']).addAnswer(
    [
        'Ingrese al siguiente link:',
        'https://appsb.mardelplata.gob.ar/Consultas/ConsuCtaAut/',
        '*0* - Volver',
        '*9* - Finalizar',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['9', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowVolver, flowGracias]
)

const flowTerciarioB_2 = addKeyword(['2']).addAnswer(
    [
        'Ingrese al siguiente link:',
        'https://appsb.mardelplata.gob.ar/consultas/ReliquidaCtaCteAutPasarelas/Index.asp',
        '*0* - Volver',
        '*9* - Finalizar',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['9', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowVolver, flowGracias]
)

const flowTerciarioC_1 = addKeyword(['1']).addAnswer(
    [
        'Ingrese al siguiente link:',
        'https://appsvr.mardelplata.gob.ar/consultas/reliquidactactemotospasarelas/index.asp',
        '*0* - Volver',
        '*9* - Finalizar',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['9', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowVolver, flowGracias]
)

// Bloques "secundarios"
const flowSecundarioA = addKeyword(['A']).addAnswer(
    [
        '*1* - Consultar Deuda',
        '*2* - Imprimir Boleta',
        '*0* - Volver',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['1', '2', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowTerciarioA_1, flowTerciarioA_2, flowVolver]
)

const flowSecundarioB = addKeyword(['B']).addAnswer(
    [
        '*Autos:',
        '*1* - Consultar Deuda',
        '*2* - Paga tu Patente',
        '*0* - Volver',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['1', '2', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowTerciarioB_1, flowTerciarioB_2, flowVolver]
)

const flowSecundarioC = addKeyword(['C']).addAnswer(
    [
        '*Motos*',
        '*1* - Paga tu Patente',
        '*0* - Volver',
    ],
    { capture: true },
    (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
        const validOptions = ['1', '0'];
        if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
            return fallBack();
        }
    },
    [flowTerciarioC_1, flowVolver]
)

// Bloque "principal"
const getFlowPrincipal = () => addKeyword(EVENTS.WELCOME)
    .addAnswer(' Hola bienvenido soy *Guillermito* Te voy a ayudar con tus trámites de *ARM*. Selecciona una opción:')
    .addAnswer(
        [
            '*A* - Inmobiliario - TSU',
            '*B* - Automóviles',
            '*C* - Motos',
        ],
        { capture: true },
        (ctx, { fallBack }) => {
            const validOptions = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
            if (!validOptions.includes(ctx.body)) {
                return fallBack();
            }
        },
        [flowSecundarioA, flowSecundarioB, flowSecundarioC]
    )

const main = async () => {
    const adapterDB = new MockAdapter();
    const adapterFlow = createFlow([getFlowPrincipal()])
    const adapterProvider = createProvider(BaileysProvider)

    createBot({
        flow: adapterFlow,
        provider: adapterProvider,
        database: adapterDB,
    })

    QRPortalWeb();
}

main()



